# Installing TFS Express 2017 fails with SQL Server Express 2017

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I have a problem when I want to install TFS Express 2017 on my machine(normal workstation) in combination with SQL Server 2017 Express which is already installed.

TFS installation seems okay until the "Review" is being executed (see pic below):

[TFS Installation fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIVu2.png)

I have also checked if the DB is running and 'connectable' via SSMS (see pic below):

[Connected to DB via SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEQJf.png)

It should be very nice if someone with the same issues has fixed this or has an answer. I am unable to find anything about the error I encounter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unambiguously telling you the problem: TFS 2017 does not support SQL Server 2017. TFS 2018 does, however.

Review the [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements).